# How do I graph the Thompson's construction using graphviz?

Tags: graph, graphviz

I am trying to graph the construction of Thompson using graphviz, and I would like to know if anyone could help me graph one of the rules so that I can do the others.

I attach a reference image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction#/media/File:Thompson-kleene-star.svg

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
    rankdir=LR;
    size="8,5"
    node [shape = doublecircle]; s3;
    node [shape = circle];
    s0 -> s1 [ label = "ε" ];   
    s0 -> s3 [ label = "ε" ];
    s1 -> s2 [ label = "ε" ];
    s2 -> s1 [ label = "ε" ];
    s2 -> s3 [ label = "ε" ];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show us you efforts so far, so we can help you on your problems.

Comment: I already uploaded what I have done

Comment: What is wrong with the output from your graphviz code?

Comment: The design is not the same

Comment: Durr - I guessed that - but be specific, for example you might attach an image of what it produces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphviz programs try to avoid placing nodes on top of other nodes.  You can get the node placement by explicitly providing **pos** attributes for all the nodes.  (Not that difficult, but a nuisance.)  You can get **neato** to generate all straight edges, but you will have to provide the (spline) coordinates for all the arcs.  Otherwise you get this:
[image]

As an alternative, instead of graphviz, if you use dpic or gpic, this program:

```
.PS

.defcolor pink rgb #FFC0CB
 circlerad=circlerad*.8

 ## we need to place the large oval before we place nodes on it
 Qx: circle invis ; line invis; circle invis; A: line invis; 
 ellipseht=ellipseht*2;  
 ellipsewid=ellipsewid*2
 E:ellipse at  A.c   shaded "pink" " N(s)"

 move to Qx.w 

 Q: circle "q" ; arrow "&#x03b5;" "";  C1: circle ; A: line invis; C2: circle ; arrow "&#x03b5;" "";  F: circle "f"; 

 circlerad=circlerad*.8
 F1:circle   at last circle   

 move to E.n; up; P1: box invis "&#x03b5;"
 arc -> from C2.n to C1.n 

 arcrad=2
 arc -> from Q.s to F.s

  ### gpic version of greek chars:
  # move to E.s; down; box invis "" "\[*e]"
  ########################################

  ###  dpic/svg version of greek chars
  move to E.s; down; box invis "" "&#x03b5;"

.PE
```

produced this:
[image]

gpic is part of the GNU (Linux) groff package.
dpic can be found here: https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~aplevich/dpic/